# Azure Data Flow wiping data from tables randomly - please assist

Tags: azure-data-factory

This is a software development question. please request any additional info that would be helpful in answering this.

I am editing a data flow that was previously working flawlessly, the new requirement is to have it still run as it did but also to filter the data (basically a where clause) and reinsert it into the database.

Order of events

Grab the data from yesterday (table 1) and move it into an archive table that has been truncated
SFTP today's data into table 1 after truncating (400k+ rows)
Data Flow 3a. 3 individual Source modules (to capture adds,removes,and title changes) with a query to filter the data 3b. Immediately dump today's and yesterday's filtered data into their sinks truncating or recreating their table first. 3c. Capture adds, removes, title changes through exists modules and attaching which it was in a derived column 3c. Union the 3 sources of changes and dump them into a change table.
My issue is caused in step 3b, some days it runs flawlessly and some days it completely empties my tables and writes 0 rows... I have even attempted separating the dumping of filtered data into sinks in a separate data flow in order to make sure it happens before capturing the changes and it still happens.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

Thanks!

[Flow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5m8A.png)

I am currently attempting to see if on completion does more than simply work as a on success or failure statement.

Comment: Provide some sample data for the requirement and dataflow JSON.